# Third degree Polynomial has the properties

Tags: polynomials, roots, cubics

> Let $p(x)$ be a polynomial of degree $3$ with real coefficients. Which of the following is possible ?
>
> a) $p(x)$ has no real roots
>
> b) $p(x) $ has exactly two real roots
>
> c) $p(1)=-1, \; p(2)=1,\; p(3)=11,\; p(4)=35$
>
> d) $i-1$ and $i+1$ are roots of $p(x)$, where $i=\sqrt{-1}$

Every odd degree real polynomial has at least one real root, so a) is false

b) is false as $x^3-1$ serve an example

d) is also false as complex roots are occur in pairs.

so c) is true.

My try for c): take $p(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+a_3x^3$ where $a_3 \neq 0$

$p(1)=-1 \Rightarrow a_0+a_1+a_2+a_3=-1$

$p(2)=1 \Rightarrow a_0+2a_1+2^2a_2+2^3a_3=1$

$p(3)=11 \Rightarrow a_0+3a_1+3^2a_2+3^3a_3=11$

$p(4)=35 \Rightarrow a_0+4a_1+4^2a_2+4^3a_3=35$

So this can be written as $$\begin{align*}\left[\begin{matrix}1&1 &1 &1\\1&2 & 2^2 & 2^3\\ 1 & 3 & 3^2 &3^3\\ 1 &4 &4^2 &4^3\end{matrix}\right]\left[\begin{matrix}a_0\\a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{matrix}\right] &= \left[\begin{matrix}-1\\1\\11\\35\end{matrix}\right]
\end{align*}$$

Since the coefficient matrix is Vandermonde, so the determinant is not zero and hence this system has a unique solution. So such a unique polynomial exist.

Is my argument correct? or any other method to show this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you solved this system?

Comment: For $b$, the question asks what is possible, not inevitable.  Therefore showing a single example for which the property does not hold does not show that $b$ is false.

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: $A^{-1}b$ is a solution where $A$ is the coefficient matrix and $b$ is a column vector on the right hand side

Comment: I know this theorem

Comment: Dr. Sonnhard Graubner: I know how to solve this system sir. My question is whether this argument is valid or not? If not, what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

d) is no impssible indeed, but the reason is the if $z\in\mathbb C$ is a root of a polynomial with real coefficients, then $\overline z$ is also a root. Therefore, $p(x)$ would have four roots: $\pm i-1$ and $\pm i+1$. That's impossible, since the polynomial has degree $3$.

Comment: $p(x)=x^3-x^2$ has exactly three roots! b) is wrong.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner If you count them with multiplicity. That's not mentioned here.

Comment: And why not? I Can not your condition. Every polynomial of degree three has exactly three Zeros.

Comment: Please correct your answer, since it is wrong!

Comment: My reason for d) means if $i-1$ is a root then $-i-1$ is also a root and similarly for $i+1$ , so it has four roots .That's what you are saying!

Comment: @LearningMathematics Please tell me: as far as you are concerned (and as far as this exercise is concerned), how many roots has the polynomial $(x-1)^2(x-2)$?

Comment: Three( with multiplicity)  sir

Comment: @LearningMathematics I've edited my answer then.

Comment: @ José Carlos Santos : ok sir what about c)?

Comment: @LearningMathematics It looks fine. That's why I didn't mention it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your thought sir!

Answer (score 1):

Your guesses are right for a,b,c and d.

For b, as many have noticed, showing an example is not enough. A suitable proof would use the fact that (as you stated) complex roots come in pairs.

For c, one possibility would be to use the [Lagrange interpolation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial). The theorem actually assesses both existence and uniqueness and is just the right fit for this question.

Comment: This one helps too! Thanks!